# .htaccess how to rewrite rule for multi .php files

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

Im using right now the next .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page1.php?$1 [QSA]
```

its working fine with `page1`, but not with `page2`

how can i make it to work please?

I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php?$2 [QSA]
```

for every php file in the folder, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say this is what you are immediately looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?page1/(.*)$ /page1.php?$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?page2/(.*)$ /page2.php?$1 [END]
```

But it might be worth to check if this cannot be generalized for arbitrary "pages":

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/(.*)$ /$1.php?$2 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you very much, yes its working without status 500